# i am getting 404 response while making http post request in flutter what am i missing

Tags: flutter

i am getting 404 response while making http post request in flutter what am i missing

```
     Future<dynamic> uploadFile({
       required XFile fileLocation,
       required String userToken,
       required String url,
       required String imageUploadLocation,
     }) async {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("$baseUrl$url");
       String fileName = File(fileLocation.path).path;
       var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

       request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(imageUploadLocation,          fileName));
       request.headers.addAll({HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: userToken, 'content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});

       http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

       return handleError(response);
     }
```

Comment: Well, normally 404 means the URL which you are trying to call is not correct or doesn't exist. Try calling API from Postman or something.

Comment: can you print and check your $baseUrl & $url may be there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you're missing anything (like a / or something) while concatenating the baseUrl with the URL in $baseUrl$url.

Comment: well url is correct does I need to add all field for request

Comment: That depends on how requests are handled at the URL you're hitting.

Try making the same request from Postman, if you get the same result there as well then it means your dart code is working fine, and something must be wrong with the URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).